# Android Alert dialog is not displayed on emulator

Tags: android, gps, android-alertdialog

I wrote code to check the GPS settings and make an alert dialog, but it doesn't show up in android emulator.

This is the code that used to check the GPS settings and show the alert dialog.

```
   package com.example.user.testlocation;

    import android.content.DialogInterface;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.location.LocationManager;
    import android.provider.Settings;
    import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.os.Bundle;

    public class Location extends AppCompatActivity {


        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_location);
        }

        private void isLocationEnalbled(){
            LocationManager locationManager=(LocationManager)getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
            if(!locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)|| !locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER)){
                AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog=new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
                alertDialog.setTitle("Enable Location");
                alertDialog.setMessage("Your locations setting is not enabled. Please enabled it in settings menu.");
                alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Location Settings", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which){
                        Intent intent=new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }
                });
                alertDialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which){
                        dialog.cancel();
                    }
                });
                AlertDialog alert=alertDialog.create();
                alert.show();
            }
            else{
                AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog=new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
                alertDialog.setTitle("Confirm Location");
                alertDialog.setMessage("Your Location is enabled, please enjoy");
                alertDialog.setNegativeButton("Back to interface",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which){
                        dialog.cancel();
                    }
                });
                AlertDialog alert=alertDialog.create();
                alert.show();
            }
        }
    }
```

It doesn't show any error, but the alert dialog doesn't display when I implement it.

Comment: Flow of control, in Android starts from onCreate() method. You need make a call to `isLocationEnabled()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You never call the `isLocationEnalbled()` method which does the check. Add this to your class, so that the app checks `isLocationEnalbled()` everytime the activity is [resumed](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle.html).

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    isLocationEnalbled();
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I really new in android programming, aha

Answer (score 0):

in your onCreate() method you have to call `isLocationEnalbled()`

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_location);
        isLocationEnalbled()
    }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It really helps a lot